# Xcode TableView Static Cells Can't Scroll to Bottom

Tags: xcode6

I'm working on a TableView with 20 static cells. I've tried a bunch of different things, but whenever I run the app it never lets me scroll to the bottom. It always shows the same exact cells no matter what I do. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Show us some code maybe? What's your implementation of 
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: can you scroll at all?

Comment: I haven't used much code. I just created a table with 20 rows and put a label on each of them. When I run the app it scrolls down, but only to the first 10. I've tried changing the height and adding constraints but no matter what it gives me the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the Attributes Inspector, there is a section that allows for scrolling.